# Pressing "Ctrl + S" by mistake while using Vim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> while using vim would result with vim to look like as if it is being locked/stuck without you being able to make more changes unless you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>.

Could someone explain what is happening and why?

> **Hint** - it might be something to do with the OS's terminal driver! ;-)

Due to a negative initial perception from the community despite having hinted that this was nothing to do with vim but some novice may search for a solution with regards to vim anyway, I would add:

- This is a duplicate question to many questions, only seen from a different perspective
- Answered at [History of Ctrl-S and Ctrl-Q for flow control](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7263) and [What is the point of Ctrl-S?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137842)
- More info about [Software flow control here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control)
- For remote hosts you can [disable Ctrl-S (XOFF) START/STOP signals](https://superuser.com/questions/124845/can-you-disable-the-ctrl-s-xoff-keystroke-in-putty)
- [Does Ctrl-S actually stop the process on terminal?](https://www.quora.com/Does-Ctrl-S-actually-stop-the-process-on-terminal)

I hope the updated question is much more useful.

Comment: Answered at [History of Ctrl-S and Ctrl-Q for flow control](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7263) and [What is the point of Ctrl-S?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/137842)

Comment: It's me being funny, I can post an answer myself :-) if people get irritated by the question I will happily delete it. Otherwise we might keep it as it could help people who are yet to experience this as they may search for a solution using different wording. Cheers!

Comment: CTRL+S in vi(m), rookie mistake.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Well, It's no a `vim` issue. This is called `Software flow control`. There is a bunch of info out there on the internet.

According to an article in [here](https://www.quora.com/Does-Ctrl-S-actually-stop-the-process-on-terminal):

> CTRL-S (XOFF) is part of Software flow control.  XOFF notifies the process or device sending data that the input buffer is full and it shouldn't send any more data.  The software (outputting process, firmware, terminal etc) can choose how to handle the notification - i.e. keep running and buffer data, drop data, pause until XON is received, etc.

More info about `Software flow control` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control).

**NOTE:** if you want to get the control of your terminal after you pressed `CTRL + s` key combination, you can press `CTRL + q`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that if it's a annoyance you can disable `Ctrl-s` on Linux by adding `stty stop ""` to one of your start-up scripts (eg `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: @AFH Is there any significance of using `stty stop ""` over [`stty -ixon`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515257/307359)? It feels hacky since `stty -ixon` is the suggested way in [`man stty`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html)

Comment: On Ubuntu in the Terminal, if I use CTRL+S, that tries to close the Terminal application but the keystroke is not going to my ssh-connected vim.
Is there a work-around to get back to working after pressing by mistake CTRL+Q?